# .htaccess - Set GET Variable everytime at the end

Tags: php, .htaccess, multilingual, language-features, language-translation

**Hi,**
momently I turn my Website to an multilanguage Website.
Problem:
I would like to Read the locale of the user from an GET variable. So the htaccess must write this locale at the end.

If this question already exists please send me the link, or is there an simpler way for the local tell it me.

Comment: Nothing to do with php, also [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using ModRewerite

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !locale=
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1?locale=DE [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I test it later